# How to run Rails 3 application on localhost/<my_port>?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, ruby-on-rails-3

To run Rails application on Windows I do:

- cd < app_dir >
- rails server

I see the following:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2011-01-12 20:32:07] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2011-01-12 20:32:07] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2010-08-18) [i386-mingw32]
[2011-01-12 20:32:07] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=5812 port=3000
```

**Question 1**

Why port 3000 is selected ? Where is it configured ?

**Question 2**

How could I run 2 applications in parallel ?
I guess I need to configure one of them to be on other port (like 3001). How should I do this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Port 3000 is the default for webrick in rails. To change the port, you can just run `rails server -p 3001`.

Run `rails server -h` for a list of all the arguments it can take.